# SQL SELECT IN returning two attributes

Tags: sql, database, select, relational

I am trying to understand SELECT IN better. Would this be a valid query?

```
SELECT name 
FROM products
WHERE product_id IN
(SELECT product_id, SUM(unit_price)
FROM sales
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING (SUM(unit_price) > 200));
```

Comment: will throw error `Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for the same reason this would not be a valid predicate:

```
WHERE product_id = (1234, 16)
```

It makes no sense to compare that one scalar is equal to a tuple.

Note that SQL does allow you to compare a tuple to a tuple:

```
WHERE (product_id, 16) = (1234, 16)
```

But the number of elements in both tuples must be the same.

And likewise you can compare a tuple to a subquery that returns a tuple:

```
WHERE (product_id, 16) IN (SELECT product_id, SUM(unit_price) FROM ...
```

As long as both tuples have the same number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

`Select` inside `In` cannot have 2 columns. This will throw an error. But since you are looking for Product Ids you dont need `SUM(Unit_Price)` anyway, the below query should work just fine:

```
SELECT name FROM products WHERE product_id IN (SELECT product_id FROM sales GROUP BY product_id HAVING (SUM(unit_price) > 200));
```

You can use inner join as well if you want to avoid `IN` part.

Comment: That depends on the database. Some certainly allow you to use multiple columns, as long as the count on both sides of the `in` are the same. i.e `(column1, column2) in (select column3, column4 from some_table)`.

Comment: Hi Srihari, thank you for your help! I would like to ask a follow up question for your query. I am a little confused because I was lead to believe that if I include a HAVING clause then the format of the SELECT should be as follows: SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value
GROUP BY column_name
HAVING aggregate_function(column_name) operator value;

Comment: Yes Hope Ashcraft, you can run without the aggregate function in select clause (atleast in oracle)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Common Tables Expressions (CTE) to achieve that

```
;WITH CTE(ProductId, UnitPrice)
AS(
SELECT product_id, SUM(unit_price) 
FROM sales 
GROUP BY product_id 
HAVING (SUM(unit_price) > 200))

SELECT [Name], c.UnitPrice
FROM Products p INNER JOIN CTE c on p.Product_Id = c.ProductId
```